# jquery, response from the POST method

Tags: jquery

I get a response from the POST method.
Inside I see the value, but after the POST method returns an empty value.
Why, hot fix this?

sample:

```
$.post('/news/add/', {parent: name, title: 'none'}, function(data){ 
 new_id = data;
 alert(new_id); //11
});
alert(new_id); //empty
```

Comment: Because of the asynchronous nature of an AJAX call.

Comment: Where is new_id declared? Or are you not declaring it with `var`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my JavaScript function not populating my array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377970/why-is-my-javascript-function-not-populating-my-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are making an asynchronous call the code is run in this order:

```
1 - $.post('/news/add/', {parent: name, title: 'none'}, function(data){ 
   3 - new_id = data;
   4 - alert(new_id); //11
});
2 - alert(new_id); //empty
```

You can only use the value returned by your post inside the callback function.

The only other way to do this is to make the request synchronous. But that's really not advised as it can lock out the browser waiting for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want to use the .complete or .success methods:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jqxhr-object